# Set selected value to @html.dropdownlistfor control

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

### My View code:

Loaded dropdown list from Viewbag

[2:35 PM] Vanita Pandya

```
var UnitList = new List<SelectListItem>();

    var tt2 = (List<Unit>)ViewBag.unitlist;

    var dunit = new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Please select Unit --", Value = "", Selected = true };

    UnitList.Add(dunit);

    UnitList.AddRange(tt2.Select(x =>

  new SelectListItem()

  {

      Text = x.UnitName,

      Value = x.UnitName

  }));

var GatepassCategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var tt5 = (List<GatePassCategory>)ViewBag.GatepassCategory;
    var dgatepass = new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Please select Gatepass Category --", Value = "", Selected = true };
    GatepassCategoryList.Add(dgatepass);
    GatepassCategoryList.AddRange(tt5.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = x.GatepassCategoryName,
    Value = x.GatepassCategoryName
}));




Unit
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m =\> m.Unit, UnitList, new { @class = "form-select" })


Gatepass Category
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(m =\> m.GatePassCategory, GatepassCategoryList, new { @onchange = "CheckGatepassvaluevalid();", @class = "form-select" })

My Controller code:
------------------
public ActionResult EditProfile(string id)
        {
            var lmbState = common.GetStateMaster();
            ViewBag.statelist = lmbState.ToList();
            var lmbunit = common.GetUnitMaster();
            ViewBag.unitlist = lmbunit.ToList();
            var lmbArea = common.GetAreaMaster();
            ViewBag.arealist = lmbArea.ToList();
            var lmbSkill = common.GetSkillMaster();
            ViewBag.skilllist = lmbSkill.ToList();
            var lmbProduct = common.GetProductMaster();
            ViewBag.productlist = lmbProduct.ToList();
            var gatepasscategory = common.GetGatepassCategoryMaster();
            ViewBag.GatepassCategory = gatepasscategory.ToList();
            //var LMBCat = common.GetLMBCategoryMaster();
            //ViewBag.LMBCatList = LMBCat.ToList();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                var empID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                var emp = applicationDbContext.Employees.Where(w => w.ID == empID).FirstOrDefault();
                emp.EmployeeUIDs = applicationDbContext.EmployeeUIDs.Where(w => w.Employees.ID == empID).ToList();
                var tt = emp.CreatedDate;
                ViewBag.pastData = applicationDbContext.Employees.Where(w => w.AadharID == emp.AadharID && w.CreatedDate < tt).FirstOrDefault();
                return View(emp);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("No profile id found!!");
            }
        }


My .CS File
-----------
public List<Unit> GetUnitMaster()
        {
            List<Unit> Unit;
            var DefaultConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(DefaultConnection))
            {
                var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Units] Where IsDeleted=0";
                SqlDataAdapter sqlCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sqlCommand.Fill(ds);

 

                Unit = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Unit
                {
                    UnitName = (string)dataRow["UnitName"],
                    ID = (int)dataRow["ID"],
                    IsDeleted = (bool)dataRow["IsDeleted"]
                }).ToList();
            }
            return Unit;
        }
public List<GatePassCategory> GetGatepassCategoryMaster()
        {
            List<GatePassCategory> GatepassCategory;
            var DefaultConnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(DefaultConnection))
            {
               
                var query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[GatepassCategories] Where IsDeleted=0";
                SqlDataAdapter sqlCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sqlCommand.Fill(ds);

 

                GatepassCategory = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new GatePassCategory
                {
                    GatepassCategoryName = (string)dataRow["GatepassCategoryName"],
                    ID = (int)dataRow["ID"],
                    IsDeleted = (bool)dataRow["IsDeleted"],
                    Age=(int)dataRow["Age"]
                }).ToList();
            }
            return GatepassCategory;
        }
```

In My view code two dropdownlist "Unit" and "GatepassCategory".
In "Unit" automatically set selected value on load. But in "GatepassCategory" dropdown it is not loaded.

My dropdownlist loaded from viewbag

Please help me on this problem.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry Please consider "Unit" at place of "Area"

Comment: You can (and should) **edit** your question instead of commenting, if changes have to be made. Also, consider using code formatting for your pieces of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share your unit list details?

Comment: public class Unit
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UnitName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

Comment: You are not binding SelectList value correctly into Viewbag. Please follow the steps I have provided. I cannot see how you are getting dropdown value, I mean selectList. Refer to this part of my solution `Load Area Controller Action:` This is the way how we can bind Viwebag from selectList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In My view code two dropdownlist "Area" and "GatepassCategory". In
> "Area" automatically set selected value on load. But in
> "GatepassCategory" dropdown it is not loaded.

Well, based on your shared code snippet and description it seems that your GatepassCategory dropdown value has not been loaded. There might be numerous reasons for that but according to your scenario, I cannot see how you are calling `CheckGatepassvaluevalid` method which is important.

Apart from that, you should call relevant controller to fetch your GatePassCategory data as well.

**How to resolve:**

Let's have a look how can we load the area dropdown and on its change event how can we load subsequent dropdown.

Demo Model:

```
public class GatePass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }

    }
```

Load Area Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult LoadArea()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> areaList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            areaList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Area-A", Value = "Area-A" });
            areaList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Area-B", Value = "Area-B" });
            areaList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Area-C", Value = "Area-C" });


            ViewBag.ListAreas = areaList;
            return View();
        }
```

**Note:** First create the dropdown list value then assign the list value into viewBag.

Gate Pass Dropdown Value Load Controller Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CheckPassByArea(string areaId)
        {

            var gatePass = new List<GatePass>()
                 {
                  new GatePass {Id = 1,Name = "Gete-A", Area = "Area-A"},
                  new GatePass {Id = 2,Name = "Gete-B", Area = "Area-B"},
                  new GatePass {Id = 3,Name = "Gete-C", Area = "Area-C"},
                 };

            SelectList gatePassList = new SelectList(gatePass.Where(ar => ar.Area == areaId), "Id", "Name");
            return Json(gatePassList);
        }
```

**Note:** I am filtering gate pass by selected area in area dropdown.

View:

```
Area DropDown: @Html.DropDownList("Area", ViewBag.ListAreas, null, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "CheckGatePassValue(this.value)" })
<hr />
Gate Pass Dropdown: <select id="GatePass" name="GatePass" class="form-control"></select>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckGatePassValue(areaId) {

        alert(areaId);
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#GatePass").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = '@Url.Action("CheckPassByArea", "ControllerName")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { areaId: areaId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select Gate Pass</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += '<option value="' + data[x].value + '">' + data[x].text + '</option>';
                }
                $("#GatePass").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**Note:** As you can see I am loading gate pass dropdown based on area name thus, I am calling CheckGatePassValue(this.value) with parameter. If you do not have any param you can just call it by CheckGatePassValue() with no parameter.

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: View Page - Time of page load

var GatepassCategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var tt5 = (List<GatePassCategory>)ViewBag.GatepassCategory;
    var dgatepass = new SelectListItem { Text = "-- Please select Gatepass Category --", Value = "", Selected = true };
    GatepassCategoryList.Add(dgatepass);
    GatepassCategoryList.AddRange(tt5.Select(x =>
new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = x.GatepassCategoryName,
    Value = x.GatepassCategoryName
}));

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You have not assign any value to `ViewBag.GatepassCategory`

Comment: Please guide how I can assign it. I have updated the whole code snippet. Please check and show me.

Comment: Try my solution I have clearly explained  the steps. First assign the value in viewbag the way I did.

Comment: In addition, assign list to your ViewBag but you are doing opposite. Like this `ViewBag.ListAreas = areaList;` Not  like `var areaList = ViewBag.ListAreas;`

Comment: Thank you so much. My issue is resolved as per your guidence

Comment: Glad to assist you on this.